# Video.js player add chromecast button?

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, chromecast, video.js

I have tried numerous ways of adding a cast button to video.js player but cannot do this for the life of me. Can anyone help?

I'm using the hellovideo cms for videos and need plugins added but have no idea about jquery etc.. so please if anyone can help?

Comment: How is downvoting this person going to help them?!

Answer (score 2):

There is a really nice plugin for this: https://github.com/kim-company/videojs-chromecast

Just follow the setup instructions (adding the js and css to your page).

Comment: i tried this and it didnt add the button at all to the player was at it for around 5 hours.

Comment: this one is working fine with videojs 5, https://github.com/ricksancho/videojs-chromecast

Answer (score 1):

**I recently answered this question, you can check it out here: [How to implement chromecast support for html5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937269/how-to-implement-chromecast-support-for-html5-player/62399655#62399655) for more information**

```js
var session = null;

$( document ).ready(function(){
        var loadCastInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if (chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
                        console.log('Cast has loaded.');
                        clearInterval(loadCastInterval);
                        initializeCastApi();
                } else {
                        console.log('Unavailable');
                }
        }, 1000);
});

function initializeCastApi() {
        var applicationID = chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID;
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
                sessionListener,
                receiverListener);
        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onInitError);
};

function sessionListener(e) {
        session = e;
        console.log('New session');
        if (session.media.length != 0) {
                console.log('Found ' + session.media.length + ' sessions.');
        }
}
 
function receiverListener(e) {
        if( e === 'available' ) {
                console.log("Chromecast was found on the network.");
        }
        else {
                console.log("There are no Chromecasts available.");
        }
}

function onInitSuccess() {
        console.log("Initialization succeeded");
}

function onInitError() {
        console.log("Initialization failed");
}

$('#castme').click(function(){
        launchApp();
});

function launchApp() {
        console.log("Launching the Chromecast App...");
        chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
}

function onLaunchError() {
        console.log("Error connecting to the Chromecast.");
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
        loadMedia();
}

function loadMedia() {
        if (!session) {
                console.log("No session.");
                return;
        }
        
        var videoSrc = document.getElementById("myVideo").src;
        var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(videoSrc);
        mediaInfo.contentType = 'video/mp4';
  
        var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
        request.autoplay = true;

        session.loadMedia(request, onLoadSuccess, onLoadError);
}

function onLoadSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully loaded video.');
}

function onLoadError() {
        console.log('Failed to load video.');
}

$('#stop').click(function(){
        stopApp();
});

function stopApp() {
        session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onStopAppError);
}

function onStopAppSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully stopped app.');
}

function onStopAppError() {
        console.log('Error stopping app.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [kim-company/videojs-chromecast](https://github.com/kim-company/videojs-chromecast). It only works with an older version of videojs, I used 5.4.6. It's quite buggy. Another I tried was [benjipott/video.js-chromecast](https://github.com/benjipott/video.js-chromecast), which claims to work with newer videojs, but I didn't like it at all. So I gave up on videojs, I always found the native HTML5 video player more reliable and easier to work with (videojs just wraps this anyway). For the chromecast stuff, I provide a nearby button that links to [chromecast.link](https://chromecast.link/), where I wrote a full web chromecast sender app. Pass the video and poster URL in the fragment, per this example:
    https://chromecast.link/#content=http://host/some.mp4,poster=http://host/poster.jpg,subtitles=http://host/webvtt.srt

Comment: There is now an example that works to cast an image. See:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937269/how-to-implement-chromecast-support-for-html5-player