# How to implement chromecast support for html5 player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, chromecast

I have designed an html5 player with some custom functionalities using js and html5,now i need to add chrome cast option on html5 player like 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kim-company/videojs-chromecast/master/screenshots/chromecast-player.jpg

The below is the link for designed html5 player
https://player14123141.herokuapp.com/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: look here - https://github.com/kim-company/videojs-chromecast

Comment: Thank for it,but i'am completely done it on  custom js and html5 and not used videojs so this plugin may not be supported .

Comment: well, the code should at least tell you how it's done, nobody here is going to write it for you, and if videojs does the thing you want to do, either use it, or copy it's functionality

Comment: checkout: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender Could this maybe help you?

Answer (score 9):

You can reuse your HTML5 player by implementing the following Google Cast Receiver interface: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.Player

You then specify your interface implementation as the media element for the MediaManager: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager

Comment: How do you implement that when working with an HTML/JS frontend?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old but I want to lay this down here for people still looking for how to make this possible it's quite simple.

**Please note you must be on a live server to make Chromecast work it won't work on a localhost server**

```js
 var session = null;

$( document ).ready(function(){
        var loadCastInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if (chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
                        console.log('Cast has loaded.');
                        clearInterval(loadCastInterval);
                        initializeCastApi();
                } else {
                        console.log('Unavailable');
                }
        }, 1000);
});

function initializeCastApi() {
        var applicationID = chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID;
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
                sessionListener,
                receiverListener);
        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onInitError);
};

function sessionListener(e) {
        session = e;
        console.log('New session');
        if (session.media.length != 0) {
                console.log('Found ' + session.media.length + ' sessions.');
        }
}
 
function receiverListener(e) {
        if( e === 'available' ) {
                console.log("Chromecast was found on the network.");
        }
        else {
                console.log("There are no Chromecasts available.");
        }
}

function onInitSuccess() {
        console.log("Initialization succeeded");
}

function onInitError() {
        console.log("Initialization failed");
}

$('#castme').click(function(){
        launchApp();
});

function launchApp() {
        console.log("Launching the Chromecast App...");
        chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
}

function onLaunchError() {
        console.log("Error connecting to the Chromecast.");
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
        loadMedia();
}

function loadMedia() {
        if (!session) {
                console.log("No session.");
                return;
        }
        
        var videoSrc = document.getElementById("myVideo").src;
        var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(videoSrc);
        mediaInfo.contentType = 'video/mp4';
  
        var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
        request.autoplay = true;

        session.loadMedia(request, onLoadSuccess, onLoadError);
}

function onLoadSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully loaded video.');
}

function onLoadError() {
        console.log('Failed to load video.');
}

$('#stop').click(function(){
        stopApp();
});

function stopApp() {
        session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onStopAppError);
}

function onStopAppSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully stopped app.');
}

function onStopAppError() {
        console.log('Error stopping app.');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Chromecast</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls src="https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4
">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<p>Click to chromecast video</p>
        <form>
                <button type="button" id="castme">Click To Cast</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Link to download the file is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J6J6suU7H4CUpMMnZOXfRQVQkeTl44j7/view?usp=sharing

This is a link to **Chromecast Images** the tutorial video in case you can't implement it yourselves https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6qrqtSGkeQ
I hope this helps a lot of people.

Comment: The link you provided is not accessible. Please insert the code here in the embedded code snippet tool.

Comment: sorry about that here is the accessible link Hope it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J6J6suU7H4CUpMMnZOXfRQVQkeTl44j7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your post. I am not trying to understand the problem/solution. My task is to help improve your answer.

Comment: >>>Hope it helps:  [ Yeah, I was hoping too, but it just doesn't work. I wish it were this easy. ]

Comment: @Dave if you don't know how to do it try watching the tutorial https://youtu.be/v6qrqtSGkeQ

Comment: @Vivflix: I now have your posted solution working.  My implementation is here : https://weasel.firmfriends.us/cc-cast/   (I changed the text of a few console-log msgs.)  But, now I have a new issue.  Your solution casts just a simple image, but the base question is asking how to cast a video-js 'player'.  So, I've tried to do that (using the same skeleton), but I can't get it to work. I think the problem is the two lines of code, specifying 'mediaInfo'.  My attempt for this is here:  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/vjs-cast/  (Maybe mime-type...I tried a few.) Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: @Dave I have edited to code to allow you to cast videos instead of images I hope it helps.

Comment: @Vivflix: Sweet...that answers it.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Vivflix Does this still work? I tried this on my server but it doesnt seem to work: interactivepixel.net/tst/s I have chromecast dongle plugged into my tv.

Comment: Just FYI: my completed example is here: https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/